# Calling layout (parent) component function from page (child) component with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

It doesn't seem like this question has been asked before for Next.js and some googling didn't really provide an answer. It's been asked specifically for React but in the Next.js framework I don't think the solution I've been using will work.

My app is basically a shop and I have a nav menu in the Layout component that wraps the app. There's Basket item in the Layout component (showing number of items) and then I have a Details component page from where I can add items to the basket.

I appreciate that it might go against the paradigm of using React (and particularly) Next.js but in the past I have solved the problem (in React and React-Router) of a child having to update the state of the parent by passing down function handlers via the props of a child. For simple applications this has often done the trick for me and solved the issue quickly.

In next JS, since I never specifically initialise the child component (Detatils page), how do I call functions of the parent component (Layout, that wraps my entire app) ?

Is this impossible without using server-side state and/or redux?

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout> {*this contains the basket icon with the number of items*}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>   
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up using React's useContext hook to do this, registering variables function handlers to a global app context. I'm not sure if this is an antipattern or ruining the point of using Netx.js.... we'll see...

Comment: you can refer to this response, that answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911883/how-do-i-implement-sibling-component-communication-in-app-shell-and-ssr/64048364#64048364 that explain how to implement a global context

Comment: Half a year in - does the design hold? was it an antipattern? Tnx

Answer (score 2):

It seems no way to get the function from `Layout` component in a specific `page` without using server-side state or `redux`.

Basically, if you want to execute the function both in `Layout` and a specific `page`, I think the right way is move the function out over the `Layout` and the `page`. As a result, define the function in `_app.js`.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    function layoutFn() {
        console.log('Execute layoutFn')
    }

    return (
        <Layout layoutFn={layoutFn}> 
            <Component {...pageProps, layoutFn} />
        </Layout>   
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

However, I think it is more reasonable to define the global function in `redux` and execute it in `Layout` or `page` by using `dispatch`.